Vertices in a straight line without distorting mesh
I have vertices that I'd like to straighten into a line without scaling to 0 on all but one axis. The vertices are part of a mesh and need to retain their position in at least 1 axis. The blue annotated line is the line angle that I'd like for the highlighted vertices. Pic 2 shows the vertices at a different camera angle to give you an idea of the vertices' position in relation to the mesh, so that hopefully you understand what I'm aiming for.
I've tried Loop tools and it hasn't worked exactly how I need it to. I know a little about scaling solutions, but not much. And I've tried some things based on my research of old posts, and that hasn't worked either. So I come seeking advice from the pros. Thanks guys


i would provide a blend file with just that mesh so that we can tell you how it could be fixed - else presumably you will say: it won't work and that might be right (because we couldn't test). I think looptools can solve that...

and one more hint: you should also click on "accept answer" (which is the checkmark left to answers) so that other people also can see that the answer you got is useful and (!) to show the people who answered here for free in their spare time a little gratitude. You did never do that....[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TMwWCdTJ.png, else there would be green color in that image.

thanks for the heads up on the accept answer thing. I overlooked that. but I'm sure people knew that I was grateful, but only through the words of my post, not the official way, as you've let me know.

you can still accept answers of your old questions. That is still possible - would be even more grateful.

Yaroslav Im going to try your suggestion. I've tried so many scaling and snapping solutions that I've got them all confused. AND thanks to Chris I'll be sure to mark it as the answer if it works. But how can it be so simple? I could have sworn I tried what you're talking about. I'll be back. Thanks for the reply.

The easiest solution is to scale these vertices along Y normal :
1) Make sure you've selected ONLY vertices you need to fix and nothing else
2) Set pivot point to median point (press . > Median Point)
3) Set orientation to normal (press , > Normal)
4) Scale to zero along Y normal axis (press S>Y>0)
That's it :-)



commented as an answer below since I don't know how to post a pic in comments. And it feels more in the flow of the information, since you answered here, I don't feel it's natural to ask a follow up question by adding or editting the original post. Rather I should ask the follow up question..... following your explanation. don't get mad at me mods
